# A combinatorial formula for different sums $a\cdot( k_1+ k_2+...+k_{n-1})+k_n$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I am looking for a combinatorial rule for the following: let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k_1,k_2,...,k_n \in \mathbb{N}$ (these are known). Since we know what the sum $\sum_{j=1}^{n}k_i$ is, let's say that $\sum_{j=1}^{n}k_i=B$.

Now, let us define a new combinatorial arrangement of $k_i$'s, let us label this as $k_{x_1},k_{x_2},...,k_{x_n}$. Also, let $a \in \mathbb{N}$ be known. Now, we want to determine how many different values may the following sum take:

$a\cdot k_{x_1}+a\cdot k_{x_2}+...+k_{x_n}=a\cdot(k_{x_1}+...+k_{x_{n-1}})+k_{x_n}$?

Here is an example: let $k_1=2$, $k_2=3$ and $k_3=1$ (i.e. $n=3$ and $k_1+k_2+k_3=6$). Now we would have the following arrangements (let $A_i$ stand for arrangement):

$\{k_{x_1},k_{x_2},k_{x_3}\}:$ $A_1=\{2,3,1\}$, $A_2=\{3,2,1\}$, $A_3=\{2,1,3\}$, $A_4=\{3,1,2\}$, $A_5=\{1,2,3\}$ and $A_6=\{1,3,2\}$.

Now, if we want to determine different described sums for these arrangements, we may see the following:

For $A_1$ we have $a\cdot(2+3)+1=5a+1$.

For $A_2$ we have $a\cdot (3+2)+1=5a+1$.

For $A_3$ we have $a\cdot (2+1)+3=3a+3$.

For $A_4$ we have $a\cdot (3+1)+2=4a+2$.

For $A_5$ we have $a\cdot (1+2)+3=3a+3$.

For $A_6$ we have $a\cdot (1+3)+2=4a+2$.

Thus, we have the total of $3$ different formulas for $a\cdot (k_{x_1}+...+k_{x_n})+k_{x_n}$. However, we do not know the exact value of $a\in \mathbb{N}$. For example, if we have $a=1$ then we would have to have $3a+3=4a+2=5a+1$, thus reducing the number of different sums to exactly $1$. However, if $a=2$ then $5a+1=11$, $3a+3=9$ and $4a+2=10$ and we would have $3$ different sums. Would there be a combinatorial formula that takes into consideration all different possibilities and would determine the exact number of different possible sums given the original $k_i$'s (in the example $k_1=2$, $k_2=3$ and $k_3=1$) and an arbitrary choice of $a \in \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 0):

You have the sum of all of the $k_i$, or any combinatorial arrangement of them, equal to a fixed and known sum, e.g., as you stated,

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}k_i = \sum_{j=1}^{n}k_{x_i} = B \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Next, for some $a \in \mathbb{N}$, your requested sum is

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}k_{x_i} + k_{x_n} & = a\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}k_{x_i} + ak_{x_n} - ak_{x_n} + k_{x_n} \\
& = a\sum_{j=1}^{n}k_{x_i} - ak_{x_n} + k_{x_n} \\
& = aB + (1 - a)k_{x_n}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

As you noticed, if $a = 1$, then the sum is always $aB$, so there's always only one possible value. Otherwise for $a \neq 1$, the number of possible values of \eqref{eq2A} is the number of distinct values of $k_i$, e.g., it will be $n$ if they are all distinct.